# How do I remove Windows SBS and just retain Windows Server and its functionality?

Tags: windows-server-2008, exchange-server-2007, windows-sbs

Ok so I acquired a new position for a business that runs Windows SBS server. Now that they have someone onsite to actually manage the network I really want to disolve SBS as soon as I can. Now I know what a lot of you are thinking, LEAVE IT ALONE!

However, I have a two fold problem.

1.) Expanding hardware resources is not an option.

2.) The company needs to go towards a more enterprise solution.

So herein lies the question, how do I remove SBS server without losing the entire server?

Comment: This question really belongs on http://serverfault.com/, which deals with questions about server administration and configuration, etc. StackExchange is all about software development and coding. You'll be more likely to get an answer over there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well ok I was able to solve one of my dilemmas. SBS Monitoring was hogging up all of the resources on the server. So I turned it off and its been working much better. Really now that I am looking at it I guess my question was how do I save resources on my SBS Server.